# Visual Studio 2019 Scoped Credential could not be imported

Tags: c#, sql-server-data-tools, visual-studio-2019

I get the following error when I try to publish my database project:

> Database Scoped Credential could not be imported but one or more of these objects exist in your source.

The interesting part is that If I try to publish the exact same project in Visual Studio 2017 then it works, but 2019 throws that error. Does anyone know why and how to fix?

I have also tried creating a new project in 2019 and copying my old files and it does not works. Same error occurs. I even tried having none of my old code and just one table called Test and it still gives the same error.

EDIT:

From .csproj File:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <!-- Default to the v11.0 targets path if the targets file for the current VS version is not found -->
    <SSDTExists Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets')">True</SSDTExists>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(SSDTExists)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

EDIT 3:

So I realized that my visual studio had an update. After which I did the deployment started working, however my post-deployment script no longer runs. I'm wondering if with visual studio 2019 they changed how they work? Currentely I have a file in `Scripts/Script.PostDeployment.sql`

Renaming the file to PostDeployment1 seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Ive had issues in the past going from older versions of VS to newer in terms of projects. Check your .csproj code of your project and ensure that the .csproj is not referencing the 2017 visual studio. Ive had an issue in the past where that exact issue prevented me from building / running code.

Comment: @davedno see my edit, do you mean this? If so, how would I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by right-clicking on "Security > Add > New Item... > Credential"